# How to detect button click event inside DataTable child row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the standard DataTable code which populates the datatable and shows child rows on row clicks.
Inside the child row (using the format function) i have added a button and i want to do something when it's clicked but each time i click the button(data table contains child row inside a new tr->td) the event of td click which is used to open/close child rows is fired and i get `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"` for the `d[]` array in format function.

This is the code for the child rows open/close:

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'td', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    table = $('#' + id).DataTable();
    var row = table.row(tr);
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
        // Open this row
        row.child(format(row.data(), id)).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
});

function format(d, id) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
if(sessionStorage['name']!=undefined)
    return '<img src="images/photo.jpg" id="photo" />' + '<p>Session created by:' + d[0] + '</p>' + '<p>Start Date:' + d.start_date + '</p>' + '<p>Extra info:' + d[3] + '</p>' + "<button class='btn btn-default' id='joinbutton' role='button'>Join Session</button>";
else
return '<div>' + '<img src="images/photo.jpg" id="photo" />' + '<p>Session created by:' + d[0] + '</p>' + '<p>Start Date:' + d.start_date + '</p>' + '<p>Extra info:' + d[3] + '</p>' + '</div>';

}
```

Is there a way to either prevent the td `click` event from being fired for child rows or to detect the button click somehow?
Thanks

Comment: you may add the event to your function $('tbody').on('click', 'td', function(e)  { so that you may test for e.target element, if it is not the right one you may stop your function, or you may handle the event stoppropagation

Comment: Being too complex to make both functions inside the same function i exctracted the button to the table into a td. thanks for the help i may come back to your answer later on

Comment: Can you please provide complete example like using JSFiddle, which will be easier to understand the exact problem.

Meanwhile you can try adding     event.stopPropagation(); inside button click event.

Answer (score 6):

I propose the snippet following my remark (see the comments, not those in the format function, they are required for me to make the snippet running):

```js
function format(d, id) {
  // `d` is the original data object for the row
  //if(sessionStorage['name']!=undefined)
    return '<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/treetog/junior/256/image-format-jpg-icon.png" id="photo" />' + '<p>Session created by:' + d[0] + '</p>' + '<p>Start Date:' + d.start_date + '</p>' + '<p>Extra info:' + d[3] + '</p>' + "<button class='btn btn-default' id='joinbutton' role='button'>Join Session</button>";
  //else
    //return '<div>' + '<img src="images/photo.jpg" id="photo" />' + '<p>Session created by:' + d[0] + '</p>' + '<p>Start Date:' + d.start_date + '</p>' + '<p>Extra info:' + d[3] + '</p>' + '</div>';

}

// to handle the joinbutton created dynamically you need:
// avoid to use the same ID for more than one element
$(document).on('click', 'button[role="button"]', function(e) {
  alert('This is the button');
});

$(function () {
  $('tbody').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
    // to avoid to receive the button click inside the td you need:
    if ($(e.target).is(':not(td)')) {
      alert('This is inside td');
      return;
    }
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    table = $('#' + id).DataTable();
    var row = table.row(tr);
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
      // Open this row
      row.child(format(row.data(), id)).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="tblId">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>Sum</td>
        <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

Add click handler to the button and return `false` from the handler to prevent default action and stop the event from propagating to parent element. Alternatively you may call [`stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) and [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

```js
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function (e) {

   // ... skipped ...

   return false;
});
```

It would be better to remove `id='joinbutton'` and use class name instead, for example `btn-join`. Then you would be able to target specific button with the code below.

```js
$('#example tbody').on('click', '.btn-join', function (e) {

   // ... skipped ...

   return false;
});
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqbax0pn/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: returning false doesn't prevent event bubbling. see below simple example

    <div onclick="alert('a');">
   <input type="submit" onclick="alert('b');return false;"/>
   </div>

Comment: @NitinGarg, see the demo where click event from the button doesn't cause other handler to be called.

Comment: Dear, please give me couple of minutes to analyse the demo.

Comment: @NitinGarg, your statement is not true. jQuery event handlers are different from handlers attached via `onclick` attribute, see [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/): *Returning false from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`.*

Answer (score 2):

I resolve my problem with @gaemaf solution:

```
// Handle click on checkbox
$("#example tbody").on("click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");

    if(this.checked){
        $row.addClass("active");
    } else {
        $row.removeClass("active");
    }

    // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
    e.stopPropagation();
});

// Handle click on table cells
$("#example tbody").on("click", "td", function(e){
    // Begin Solution
    if ($(e.target).is(':not(td)')) {
        return;
    }
    // End solution
    $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger("click");
});
```